# No aparecen los datos del sql en formulario

Tags: php, html, formularios, sql-server-2008

Estoy probando una opción para añadir a mi formulario. Consiste en una opción `select` que contenga los nombres de los empleados que están guardados en una base de datos alojada en MySQLServer 2008.
Para ello, utilicé el código que vi en [www3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) para lograr hacer lo mismo que en el ejemplo, pero una vez implementado, cambiando los datos por los de mi tabla, no funciona. Literalmente, selecciono un nombre, y no me aparece ninguna tabla ni ninguna información.

Este es el código que tengo

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select a person:</option>
      <option value="1">Luis</option>
      <option value="2">Nora</option>
      <option value="3">Aron</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**getuser.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('192.168.9.10','sa','','logytel');
if (!$con) {
    die('No se pudo conectar ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>;
<tr>;
<th>Código</th>;
<th>Nombre</th>;
<th>Apellidos</th>;
<th>Proyecto</th>;
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>"
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Y estos son los datos de mi tabla
[image: Datos]

Y cuando selecciono un nombre...

[image: Seleccion]

No sé si he cambiado algo del código que no debía, o si no he cambiado algo que debía cambiar. La conexión con la base de datos se realiza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('192.168.9.10','sa','','logytel'); 
if (!$con) {
    die('No se pudo conectar ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Código</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellidos</th>
<th>Proyecto</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificarme que has añadido/modificado? Gracias

Comment: Este es el archivo corregido, probando en mi base de datos local, **funciona perfectamente**.

Comment: `echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Código</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellidos</th>
<th>Proyecto</th>
</tr>";`  agregue el  **;**

Comment: Me aparece este error `(index):23 GET http://logytel.es/formulario_sql/getuser.php?q=3 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: una pregunta para tratar de solucionar, en tu base de datos, no has guardado código con acento? ya que en la imagen adjunta a tu pregunta, el mismo aparece así.

Comment: No, probando después de poner la pregunta, cambié tanto la mayúscula como las tildes. Ahora está todo en minúscula, y sin acentos.

Comment: puedes mandarme un .zip con tu proyecto? así lo miro (orlandomartinez.994@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando realizas echo de tu tabla (antes del `WHILE`) en el archivo `getuser.php`, te falto poner `;` (punto y coma), **solo eso seria el error** (dado que confirmas que existe la conexión a la base de datos).

Comment: Añadir ";" después de cada línea, ¿no?

Comment: No, solo al finalizar una sentencia o asignación ejemplo: `echo "esto es un ejemplo";`, siempre puedes verificar si existen errores utilizando las herramientas de inspección del navegador.

Comment: Acabo de poner los ; y me sale en cuanto indico un nombre "No se pudo conectar", en cambio la ip está bien, tanto el usuario como la contraseña. Y con el programa dbeaver.io, me indica que se establece la conexión. Miré la consola del navegador y no me dice ningún error.

Comment: Otra recomendación que te daría es, utilizar _localhost_ en vez de la IP, cuando realizas la conexión a la base de datos, el error del `;` es en la linea 19 (utilizando Sublime Text).

Comment: El caso es que la base de datos no está en el mismo servidor en el que tengo el php, está en otro de la misma red. 

En la línea 19 hay un espacio en blanco, antes del <?php y después del <body>